# How can I show more of my border image on the bottom with css border-image?

Tags: css, border-image

I'm using css-border-image to put TV show posters into an image of a horizontal TV that has a stand at the bottom, so the image isn't supposed to be centered in the border-image - I want to get it to go a little higher up, or stretch the border-image vertically so the image fits in the right place.

```css
.tv {
  height: 170px;
  border: 9px solid transparent;
  border-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyxRN.png") 15 stretch;
}
```

```html
<img class="tv" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWFjODRhMDktMTE3My00ODQzLThmODctYmM2ZmU5YmY0ZGVkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMjkwOTAyMDU@._V1_.jpg">
```

Things I've tried:

- Adding a `border-bottom: 20px` line (this only stretches out the TV stand)
- Using `round` and `stretch` with different numbers
- Using `border-image-outset`
- Trying `border-image-slice`

Can I make the image **not** be centered in its border-image? Please tell me there's a solution that only edits the css in `.tv` without having to put it in a container!

Comment: Does it have to be a border as opposed to a background image? And do all the posters have the same aspect ratio as each other?

Comment: It is a background image! - They have the same or very similar aspect ratios so I don't mind cropping them slightly if it comes to that.

Comment: Betule, what @AHaworth is asking - I think - is rather than using a border-image for the TV frame, would it be possible to use a background-image instead to create the illusion of an image being shown on a TV? Or does it have to be a border-image?

Comment: OH! Yes, I could try making it a background image. Thank you both. :)

Comment: Give the img element some padding (less at the top, more at the bottom - calculated so all the TV shows.

Comment: I did `background-image` and was trying to fix the fragmented image until someone else posted the answer haha (just `background`) -- solved

Answer (score 0):

Some padding with background-image would be easier

```css
.tv {
  height: 170px;
  padding: 6px 8px 20px;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyxRN.png") 0/100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<img class="tv" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWFjODRhMDktMTE3My00ODQzLThmODctYmM2ZmU5YmY0ZGVkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMjkwOTAyMDU@._V1_.jpg">
```

Comment: Yayyy thank you! I gave it a vote but I don't have enough reputation for them to show it

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find some fitting values for `border-image-slice`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice

```css
.tv {
  height: 170px;
  border: 9px solid transparent;
  border-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyxRN.png") stretch;
  border-image-slice: 10 10 62;
}
```

```html
<img class="tv" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWFjODRhMDktMTE3My00ODQzLThmODctYmM2ZmU5YmY0ZGVkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMjkwOTAyMDU@._V1_.jpg">
```

Comment: Oh that's cool, I didn't realize I could add more than one number to `border-image-slice`. Thank you. :)

PS check out the other answer! They used `background` instead of `border-image` so the bottom part doesn't get squished.